# How to call nested function in jquery which is another file?

Tags: php, jquery

I want use other file jquery function to my page.

**Below is "mathml2latex" file code**

```
function MathMLParser() {
    this.parse = function MathMLParser$parse(s) {
        console.log('123');
        return true;
    };
}
```

I have loaded above file in my html page. Also checked twice for correctly added or not.

Here is my html page where i want to use above Js file function.

```
<html>
     <head>
           <title>Mathml to Latex</title>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="mathml2latex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $( document ).ready( function() {
                   var mathmlHtml  = 'how to call function.';
                   var x = MathMLParser.parse( mathmlHtml );
               });
           </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

But i don't know how to call above function. I have tried many way like create new object but and then call `parse` function. so how to deal with that??

So My question is how to call `parse` function in my html page.

Comment: MathMLParser$parse looks like JAVA and not JavaScript. Where do you load the `MathMLParser` library?

Comment: @mplungjan I have load this library on my html page. `mathml2latex.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute a function using an object you could use something like that :

```js
class MathMLParser {
    parse = () => {
        console.log('123');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
           <title>Mathml to Latex</title>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="mathml2latex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
           <script type="text/javascript">
                let MathMLParserInstance = new MathMLParser();

               $( document ).ready( function() {
                   var mathmlHtml  = 'how to call function.';
                   var x = MathMLParserInstance.parse();
               });
           </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

But i suggest you start using import/export to give your code a better structure.